# Subtracting calculated values from two different tables in SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

In my program, a user can earn points at a venue by performing check-ins at that venue.

They can then use those points to redeem rewards at that venue. Points are not shareable across venues.

I have the following tables:

**users**

- id
- name

**venues**

- id
- name

**check_ins**

- id
- user_id (FK): The user who earnt the point
- venue_id (FK): The venue in which the user earned points in
- points: The amount of points earned

**rewards**

- id
- name
- venue_id: The venue the reward belongs to
- points: The amount the reward cost

**reward_redemptions**

- id
- user_id
- reward_id

I can calculate the total points a user has by venue like so:

```
select venue_id, sum(points) as total_points
from check_ins
WHERE user_id = 109
group by venue_id, user_id;
```

I can calculate the number of points redeemed by venue like so:

```
select venue_id, sum(points) as points_redeemed
from reward_redemptions
JOIN rewards on reward_redemptions.reward_id = rewards.id
GROUP BY venue_id;
```

I can then use a programming language (e.g. PHP) to calculate the points remaining for each venue by subtracting them.

However, I want to use SQL to do this (ideally in 1 query, to reduce the chances of data being changed between queries, make code simpler, and potentially increase performance). The end result would ideally be this:

```
venue_id    total_points    points_redeemed     points_remaining      
#5          10              2                   8
#15         25              10                  15
#189        150             20                  130
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to get total points and points redeemed all in one query?
2. Is it possible to get total points, points redeemed and points remaining in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `group by`.  Here is the query about venues and points:

```
select venue_id, sum(total_points) as total_points,
       sum(points_redeemed) as points_redeemed
from ((select venue_id, sum(points) as total_points, 0 as points_redeemed
       from check_ins
       group by venue_id
      )
      union all
      (select venue_id, 0 as total_points, sum(points) as points_redeemed
       from reward_redemptions rr join
            rewards r
            on rr.reward_id = r.id
       group by venue_id
      )
     ) p
group by venue_id;
```

The difference can easily be calculated by subtracting the sums.

Comment: I think there is a syntax error in your code. I think you forgot the union bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables to combine them.

```
SELECT c.venue_id, c.user_id
        SUM(c.points) AS total_points, 
        IFNULL(r.points_redeemed, 0) AS points_redeemed, 
        SUM(c.points) - IFNULL(r.points_redeemed, 0) AS points_remaining
FROM check_ins AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    select venue_id, user_id, sum(points) as points_redeemed
    from reward_redemptions
    JOIN rewards on reward_redemptions.reward_id = rewards.id
    GROUP BY venue_id, user_id) AS r
ON c.venue_id = r.venue_id AND c.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY c.venue_id, c.user_id
```

The left join is necessary to include users who haven't redeemed anything yet.